# Navigate to record page from Leaflet Marker Popup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I created a custom Lightning component that displays "Incidents" on a Leaflet map with Markers and a Popup for each Marker. We have a requirement to let the user navigate to the Incident record (sObject) from a link in the marker popup. My approach so far has been to try to put the navigate function in the popup content.

The closest I've come is a function that works, but it fires just after the map markers and popups are created. The user never has a chance to interact with the map.

```
// Create map markers and bind popups
    for (var i=0; i<incidents.length; i++) {
        var item = incidents[i];

        var latLng = [item.Location__r.lat__c, item.Location__r.lon__c];
        var imageURL = this.getMarkerPin(cmp, item.Severity__c);
        var myIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: imageURL,
            iconSize: [16, 16],
            iconAnchor: [0, 0],
            popupAnchor: [-3, -3]
        });
        var options = {icon: myIcon, incident: item};
        var navObj = this.getNewNavObject(item.Id);

        L.marker(latLng, options).addTo(markers).bindPopup(
        '<strong>Location: ' + item.Location__r.Name + '</strong><br>'  + 
        '<a href="' + navObj.navToRecord() + '">' + item.Name + '</a><br>' + item.Severity__c);
};
```

I thought putting my Navigate function in an object would help, but it made no difference

```
// create a new Nav Object 
    getNewNavObject : function (recId){

    // constructor function  
    var NavObject = function (string) {
        this.recordId = string;
    };
    // Give all instances of NavObject a public navigate method
    NavObject.prototype.navToRecord = function(){
        return $A.get('e.force:navigateToSObject').setParams({ 'recordId' : this.recordId}).fire();
    }
    return new NavObject(recId);
}
```

Similar questions about Leaflet popup content have been asked here, but I haven't found any with answers. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified things a bit and got this to work by creating the URL string directly instead of using force:navigateToSObject. It's not ideal. If I ever learn how to properly leverage Lightning component functionality from the Marker Popup I'll update this post.

I'm creating the URL like so

```
var urlString = window.location.href;
var baseURL = urlString.substring(0, urlString.indexOf("/p"));
var navToRecURL = baseURL + '/r/Incident__c/' + item.Id + '/view';
```

and the Popup content:

```
L.marker(latLng, options).addTo(markers).bindPopup(
    '<strong>Location: ' + item.Location__r.Name + '</strong><br>'  + 
    '<a href="' + navToRecURL + '">' + item.Name + '</a></strong><br>' + 
    item.Severity__c);
```